# Android Soundboard Force Close

Tags: android

I have a soundboard where i am trying to save the sounds as ringtones or notifications you can see the code below, the problem i am having is when i try to save the sound the app force closes on me.

Sometimes the code worked and saved but othertimes it force closed but now it seems to force close all the time. This is also after i have restared the app?

If anyone can take a look it would be appriciated.

Thanks.

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {


int selectedSoundId;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    final Resources res = getResources();

    //just keep them in the same order, e.g. button01 is tied to backtoyou
    final int[] buttonIds = { R.id.PlaySound1, R.id.PlaySound2, R.id.PlaySound3, R.id.PlaySound4, R.id.PlaySound5,};
    final int[] soundIds = { R.raw.bentonirate, R.raw.bentonlong, R.raw.bentonshort, R.raw.ohjesuschrist, R.raw.ohjesuschristbenton, };

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //find the index that matches the button's ID, and then reset
            //the MediaPlayer instance, set the data source to the corresponding
            //sound effect, prepare it, and start it playing.
            for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
                if(v.getId() == buttonIds[i]) {
                    selectedSoundId = soundIds[i];
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(soundIds[i]);
                    player.reset();
                    try {
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        player.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    player.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };



    //set the same listener for every button ID, no need
    //to keep a reference to every button
    for(int i = 0; i < buttonIds.length; i++) {
        Button soundButton = (Button)findViewById(buttonIds[i]);
        registerForContextMenu(soundButton);
        soundButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }



}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Save as...");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Ringtone");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Notification");
}
@Override   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}   
  else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
  else {return false;}
 return true; 
}

public void function1(int id){  

    if 
     (savering(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Ringtone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    }
    public void function2(int id){   
     if 
     (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
      // Code if successful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Saved as Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }           
     else           
     { 
      // Code if unsuccessful   
      Toast.makeText(this, "Failed - Check your SDCard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }
    }



//Save into Ring tone Folder

public boolean savering(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=50; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/ringtone/";


 String filename="Benton"+".ogg";


 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
 getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
 Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);




 return true; 
}

//Save in Notification Folder

public boolean savenot(int ressound){
 byte[] buffer=null;
 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
 int size=0; 

 try {
   size = fIn.available();   
   buffer = new byte[size];   
   fIn.read(buffer);   
   fIn.close(); 
 } catch (IOException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;      } 

 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/notification/";


 String filename="Benton"+".ogg";

 boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();   
 if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}   

 FileOutputStream save;
 try { 
  save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);   
  save.write(buffer);   
  save.flush();   
  save.close();   
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;  
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
  return false;
 }
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename))); 

 File k = new File(path, filename);   
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Benton");   
 values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "weee");   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);   
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);    

 Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
 getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
 Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
 RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);


 return true; 



}
}
```

LogCat on force close:

```
            11-29 11:26:28.963: W/ResourceType(3312): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    11-29 11:26:28.963: W/dalvikvm(3312): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc7d0)
    11-29 11:26:28.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3312): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    11-29 11:26:28.963: I/global(3312): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    11-29 11:26:29.003: I/global(3312): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    11-29 11:26:29.003: W/System.err(3312): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    11-29 11:26:29.033: I/global(3312): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:895)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:820)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:802)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.savenot(Activity2.java:210)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.function2(Activity2.java:131)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.Tutorial.Sound.Activity2.onContextItemSelected(Activity2.java:110)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2199)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2744)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:874)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4635)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    11-29 11:26:29.033: E/AndroidRuntime(3312):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-29 11:26:29.073: I/global(3312): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    11-29 11:26:29.083: W/System.err(3312): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
    11-29 11:26:29.143: I/global(3312): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    11-29 11:26:29.143: W/System.err(3312): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will come across this crash when an item on the contextual menu is selected. 
.

What you are actually passing to `savering()` is actually the menu item id which are integers (0, 1, 2 ...), you should somehow translate these positions to indexes in `soundIds`. 
I can't see where this mapping is done in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man is it possible you can help me out on what code to add and where to add it?